# Initialize an array directly with an algorithm and the check values inside

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I need to generate some numbers and use that list as a validation for the user input. Luckily, I figured it out how to get the correct numbers in the correct sequence but I'm struggling to pass this list into an array. (or something else)

```
for (int e = 1; e <= max_event_number; e++) {
            int total_events_by_year =  first_event + (e * event_occurence);
```

//I get 22 correct numbers when I `cout << total_events_by_year`. But... since they are stored in an `int` are they treated as separate values?

// Here I try to initialize an array in my own special way... (it compiles)

```
for (int e = 1; e <= max_event_number; e++) {
            int total_events_by_year[] = { first_event + (e * event_occurence) };
```

//I think I get 22 * memory address of index 0 of the array when << cout.

I can validate user input with 6 * `if` statements which can cover dates beyond first event, future events, years without events - but having a list with all possible events it looks like a better solution...

Comment: `std::vector<int> total_events_by_year; for (...) { total_events_by_year.push_back(first_event + (e * event_occurence)); }`?

Comment: No you don't get 22 memory addresses, int total_events_by_year[] shouldn't even compile (its an empty array declaration), instead \have a look at std::vector and push_back

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's 22 * the same value if I try to generate an array.

Comment: I was talking about the second example. However in both examples total_events_year is no longer accessible outside the scope of the for loop. A scope begins with '{' and ends at '}' and determines the life-cycle of objects/variables inside it. What you should do is have some variable or object outside the scope of the for loop to store your data in. The best datastructure for this is the std::vector as it can grow in size unlike a normal array for which you need to know the size at compile time.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: And if you want to ask about behavior of some code you currently have, then please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your array *outside* of the loop and assign each index to the specified value:

```
int total_events_by_year[22] = {};
for (int e = 0; e < max_event_number; e++) {
            total_events_by_year[e] =  first_event + (e * event_occurence);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use std::array in the array header:

```
std::array<int, 22> total_events_by_year;
for(int e = 0; e < max_event_number; e++){
    total_events_by_year.at(e) = first_event + (e * event_occurence);
}
```

**Edit:** To see if a number is in the array( for both snippets), include algorithm and iterator and use the following code (let user_in = the user's input):

```
if(std::find(std::cbegin(total_events_by_year), 
    std::cend(total_events_by_year), user_in) != 
    std::cend(total_events_by_year)){ // replace user_in with the users input
    // logic if users input is in the array goes here
}
```

Comment: First piece of code will compile, second gives an error.

Comment: Compiling the code I get the same output with 'cout' (22 * 003BFAA8 or some othe address) . Now how I check if an user input number is in this particular array? I tried some lame code with no succes: 'if (input_year = !total_events_by_year) {
  
   std::cout << "This is not a valid date! " << std::endl;'

Comment: @AlexPina Sorry, in the second snippet had a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @AlexPina To check if the user input number is in this particular array, see my updated answer.